# hive/impala - inserted decimal showed as null

Tags: impala, cloudera-cdh

I created table as

```
create table test ( x decimal(5,2))
```

then I tried to insert a value

```
insert into test values ( cast( 1000.2  as decimal(5,2) ) );
insert into test values ( cast('2000.3' as decimal(5,2) ) );
insert into test values ( cast('3000,4' as decimal(5,2) ) );
```

but in the end `select * from test;` is returning 3x NULL value.

What I'm doing wrong ? I can't believe any of above mentioned statements doesn't work.

*I'm using impala at recent Cloudera quickstart VM*.

Comment: Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2

Comment: @Bala 
when I insert just number without casting its 
`AnalysisException: Possible loss of precision for target table 'default.test'. Expression '1000.2' (type: DECIMAL(5,1)) would need to be cast to DECIMAL(5,2) for column 'x' `

I tried to round number to have less then 5 digits by 
`insert into test values ( cast(  round(3000.5) as decimal(5,2)));` even this ends up as NULL.

Comment: What happens with 100.2?

Comment: oh you are right ! 1000.2 is NULL but 100.2 is OK. So it appears "dot" as also considered ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2

```
select cast(1000.2 as decimal(5,1)) as a, 
       cast(1000.2 as decimal(5,2)) as b,
       cast(1000.2 as decimal(6,2)) as c
```

will give you

```
a   1000.2
b   NULL
c   1000.2
```